# TripAdvisor Lockscreen Folder Path

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I'm trying to find TripAdvisor's lockscreen folder on my Samsung Note 3. Can you please tell me where it is ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it under,

`/data/data/com.samsung.android.service.travel/`

But you need `root` permission to access this directory. If you have unrooted phone please have a look into this quesion on [How to root your android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device)